# change image size wih jquery

Tags: android, image, resize, image-size

I have a image under div id myimage. Now I want to resize it by using change. I want from select box if selected 700X7000 then image's size will be height 700px and width 700px. With out reloading the page.
Can any one help me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set new `new LayoutParams(200, 200)` everytime.

```
screenDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
dimInDP = 200 * (screenDensity/(float)160)
imageTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dimInDP ,dimInDP ));
```

**EDIT :** The Android system takes 160dpi as the reference density for density independent pixel calculation. For example, in your case you need dimension as 200dp. The system takes this as the numbersof pixels you want on a device of screen density 160dpi. So at runtime it scales the width relative to the reference density. 
Assume you run ur app on a screen density 120. The view width will be scaled to 150 physical pixels.

Comment: I really don't understand this new LayoutParams(200, 200), is it on dp or px?

Comment: how do you convert it? So what do I really have to put in my code in order to convert it into DP?

Comment: I am really confuse with your code, do you have any easy explanation to accomplish this? Please I really need this badly

Comment: I addded explanation. Hope it helps. Also note the float typecast in the formula as it will return ratio of densities.